# Is {1,4,2} represented by a primitive Type in Java?

Tags: java, primitive-types

Do Numbers inside such brackets { } always belong to arrays or can it be a primitive Type too?

The exact task is: Decide for the following values (!) whether Java provides primitive data types for their representation. If yes, specify all matching ones.

I'm only not sure about this one: {1,4,2}
There isn't any int [ ] infront of that, that's why i'm asking.

(sorry for the dumb question, very big noob here)

Comment: The contents are primitive, the array is not

Comment: If you mean the Java code `new int[] {1, 4, 2}` then no, that's an array which is a reference type, not a primitive type. If you mean the mathematical set (or sequence) {1, 4, 2}, then there are ways of representing sets or sequences of small numbers by encoding them in the bits of a primitive numeric type. Whether or not something in a program represents something outside of the program is always (more or less) a matter of interpretation.

Comment: Arrays are reference types. `Object o = new int[] {1,4,2};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code :

```java
int[] array = {1,2,3};
```

Is equivalent to :

```java
int[] array = new int[3];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
```

In java, arrays are objects (even if it's an array of primitive type)